# Batch file not recognizing >> character

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to append the contents of one file to another using the >> operator in a batch file. However, it is not accepting the >> How do I make this work?

```
  set S1=type "\\scc-fs\common\Accounting\2_AcctsPayable\5_Expense_Distribution\3_MAR\tmp.xls"
  set s2=>>
  set s3="\\scc-fs\common\Accounting\2_AcctsPayable\5_Expense_Distribution\3_MAR\%filename%.xls"
  set scopy=%s1% %s2% %s3%
  %scopy%
```

Comment: It looks like you are working with Excel files. You cannot just combine the text/binary data to merge them. You would need to do this through Excel itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes

```
  set "S1=type "\\scc-fs\common\Accounting\2_AcctsPayable\5_Expense_Distribution\3_MAR\tmp.xls""
  set "s2=>>"
  set "s3="\\scc-fs\common\Accounting\2_AcctsPayable\5_Expense_Distribution\3_MAR\%filename%.xls""
  set "scopy=%s1% %s2% %s3%"
  %scopy%
```

Comment: Can you put double quotes inside of double quotes like that?